# Automation Github with GCP

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, webhooks, google-cloud-run

So I need to make automation on nodejs application on GCP.
The idea is, I need to deploy the web app (nodejs) with `cloud run` but every time a developer
did push on Github the image should be rebuild and deployed automatically. The constraint is that I need to use  *webhooks* to send me notification that a push is done.
Can some of you give me some directions or steps how to make this work?

Comment: What have you tried or read so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth to try [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build).

1. There is possibility to build with node.js ([Node.js Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-nodejs)).
2. There is possibility to deploy in Cloud Run ([Deploy with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run)).
3. Finally there is a possibility to setup trigger on GitHub push ([GitHub triggers](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-github-app-triggers#creating_github_app_triggers_2)).

I think that even this *webhook constraint* is not needed in this case... However there is [push notification](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications) feature as well.